# map 2 array of object and populate boolean array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have this first array, at the end of each item it has numerical value.

```
const arr = ["abc#1","def#2","z#1", "z#2"]
```

I have to map it with below array

```
const arrObj = [{
  name: 'abc'
},{
  name: 'def'
},{
  name: 'z'
}]
```

to populate a new property value that has boolean in array

```
result = [{
  name: 'abc',
  value: [true, false]
},{
  name: 'def',
  value: [false, true]
},{
  name: 'z',
  value: [true, true]
}]
```

I'm stuck at doing multiple iteration but failed to produce above result.

```
const arr = ["abc#1","def#2","z#1", "z#2"]

let arrObj = [{
  name: 'abc'
},{
  name: 'def'
},{
      name: 'z'
    }]

const raw = arr.map(o => o.split('#')[0])
const key = arr.map(o => o.split('#')[1])

arrObj = arrObj.map(o => {

  console.log('raw', raw)

  if(raw.includes(o.name)) {
    console.log('key', key)
    console.log(o.name)
  }

  return {
    ...o,
    value: []
  }
})
```

Comment: Post function(s) and/or a cohesive group of statements and/or expressions in JavaScript as a [mcve]. Also an object with duplicate keys is invalid (ex. `{  value: 'z',  value: [true, true] }` two `value:` is invalid)

Comment: @zer00ne thanks, saw, that. I'm stuck :(

Comment: I'm not sure where do the boolean values in the `value` array come from. Could you be more specific on that? Like, why the first array is `[true, false]` and the second is `[false, true]` and the last is `[true, true]`

Comment: @user3106579 Shouldn't `name: 'z'` be included in `arrObj`?

Comment: @zer00ne yup. Edited.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek if the numberical value is 1 means it's first position of the array, if it's 2 then it's second position of the array

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to combine two different arrays or just map one array into another? In the result array, the `name` property is just the text of the items in the first array without the number? What determines the values of the booleans? And please add examples of what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (**UPDATED**) solution:

```js
const arr = ['abc#1', 'def#2', 'z#1', 'z#2', 'anotherName#4'];

const arrObj = [
  { name: 'abc' },
  { name: 'def' },
  { name: 'z' }, 
  { name: 'anotherName' }
];

// find min and max IDs
let minId;
let maxId;
arr.forEach(str => {
  const id = +str.split('#')[1];
  minId = typeof minId === 'undefined' || id < minId ? id : minId;
  maxId = typeof maxId === 'undefined' || id > maxId ? id : maxId;
});

// build array of integers staring from minId to maxId including
const arrSize = maxId - minId + 1;
const booleanArr = Array.from(Array(arrSize)).map((_, i) => minId + i);

const arrMap = arr.reduce((res, curr) => ({
  ...res,
  [curr]: 1
}), {});

const result = arrObj.map(({name}) => ({
  name,
  value: booleanArr.map(i => Boolean(arrMap[`${name}#${i}`]))
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: will it work if there's new key like 'anotherName#4' ?

Comment: please give an example of such new scenario, and what should it influence on

Comment: I updated my answer and removed O(N x N) version, does it fit your task?

Comment: is order of id names is important in `arrObj ?

Comment: why can't use make distinctIds variable simpler? before object.value u store it as object with the same key, like {1:1, 2:2}. what's the intention? can't the reduce return array?

Comment: search in array is more expensive than in a map or SET, that is the only reason I used a map with O(1) search. And this is only for sake of  `booleanArr ` array creation. I use only values of `distinctIds` map, which is an array of integers

Comment: sorry for my misunderstanding of your point. You are absolutely right , we can use `Array.map()` which simplifies things a lot... I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: I further simplified my solution by removing `distinctIds` array at all and just calculating `minId` and `maxId`

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to each Object of the Array of Objects (`objArray`):

```
objArray.forEach(object => object.value = [false, false]);
// ex. value: [false, false]
```

Then `.split()` each String of the Array of Strings (`strArray`) at the hash `#`

```
let subArray = string.split('#');
// ex. ["abc", "1"]
```

Convert the second string into a real index number. **Note: this step is unnecessary if the strings were properly numbered -- ex. `const strArray = ["abc#0", "def#1", ...]`**

```
let index = Number(subArray[1]) - 1;
```

Iterate through `objArray` again and set each element within sub-array `value` to `true` according to matching `object.name` and `subArray[0]` and the corresponding `index` number.

```
object.value[index] = true;
```

---

#### Demo

**Details are also commented in demo**

```js
const strArray = ["abc#1", "def#2", "z#1", "z#2"];
let objArray = [{
  name: 'abc'
}, {
  name: 'def'
}, {
  name: 'z'
}];

/*
Assign each object in objArray defaults to:
value: [false, false]
*/
objArray.forEach(object => object.value = [false, false]);

// Uncomment line below to view in console 
/*
console.log(`~~~~~~~ objArray - initial state ~~~~~~~`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(objArray));
console.log(`~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
console.log(`~~~~~~~ Sub-arrays from strArray ~~~~~~~`);
*/

for (let string of strArray) {
  /*
  Convert each string of strArray to a subArray:
  ex. ["abc", "1"]
  */
  let subArray = string.split('#');
  // Convert the second string into a real index number
  let index = Number(subArray[1]) - 1;

  for (let object of objArray) {
    /*
    if object name matches the first string of a subArray...
    Change the object value to true at the index previously defined
    */
    if (object.name === subArray[0]) {
      object.value[index] = true;
    }
  }
  // Uncomment line below to view in console 
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(`['${subArray[0]}', '${subArray[1]}'] --> object.value index: ${index}`));
}

console.log(`~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
console.log(`~~~~~~~~ objArray - final state ~~~~~~~~`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(objArray));
console.log(`~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
```

---

#### [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) Loops

**Note:** this is not directly related to answer. This is a reply to a comment below:

> *but you can't have index in `for...of`* – **user3106579**

Refer to [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries#Iterating_with_index_and_element) of the MDN section on [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) method.

```js
const paragraphs = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')];

for (let [index, paragraph] of paragraphs.entries()) {
  if (index % 2 !== 0) {
    paragraph.style.color = 'tomato';
  }
}

paragraphs.forEach((paragraph, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    paragraph.style.color = 'blue';
  }
});

for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 !== 0) {
    paragraphs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#000';
  }
}
```

```css
*>* {
  margin-left: 15px
}

p {
  width: max-content;
  margin-left: 30px
}

main,
h1,
section,
h2,
article,
h3 {
  margin-top: -40px: margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Main</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Section A</h2>
    <p>Paragraph aa</p>
    <p>Paragraph ab</p>
    <article>
      <h3>Article A1</h3>
      <p>Paragraph A1a</p>
      <p>Paragraph A1b</p>
      <p>Paragraph A1c</p>
    </article>
    <p>Paragraph ac</p>
    <article>
      <h3>Article A2</h3>
      <p>Paragraph A2a</p>
      <p>Paragraph A2b</p>
    </article>
    <p>Paragraph ad</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Section B</h2>
    <p>Paragraph ba</p>
    <article>
      <h3>Article B1</h3>
      <p>Paragraph B1a</p>
      <p>Paragraph B1b</p>
      <p>Paragraph B1c</p>
      <p>Paragraph B1d</p>
    </article>
    <p>Paragraph bb</p>
    <p>Paragraph bc</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: sometime using raw for loop like this solve problem better than using es6 loops

Comment: A `for` loop is great for generating two-dimensional arrays, but I prefer  `for...of` loops because there is less code to write. Also the `.keys()`, `.values()`, `.entries()` methods, and destructuring patterns can be used for more complex situations.

Comment: but you can't have index in ```for...of```

Comment: @user3106579 see update at the end of the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60969436/2813224) -- titled as: ***`for...of`` Loop***.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```js
const arr = ["abc#1","def#2","z#1", "z#2", "anotherName#4"]
      
const boolLength = arr.reduce((r, x) => {
  const [a, b] = x.split('#');
  return +b > r ? b : r
}, 0);

const tempObject = arr.reduce((r, x) => {

  const [a, b] = x.split('#');

  const array = r[a] || Array.from({length: boolLength}, (x, i) => false)
  array[b - 1] = true;

  return { 
   ...r,
   [a]: array
};

}, {});


const result = Object.keys(tempObject).reduce((r, x) => [
  ...r, 
  {
    name: x,
    value: tempObject[x]
  }
], []);
      
console.log(result);
```

First, store in `boolLength` the boolean array max lenght. Then store ìn `tempObject` an object to prevent repeating `name` properties. And last, in `result` compose the array.